# Square and multiply two rows from two different files -Perl

Tags: perl, file, row, multiplication

How can I square and then multiply two rows from two different files using Perl?
Here are my two files:

```
file1:
ID_A    AAA BBB CCC DDD FFF LLL 
ID_B    F   F   L   L   L   L   
SCORE    0.750   0.000   0.857   0.857   1.286   0.000  

file2:
ID_A    AAA BBB CCC DDD FFF LLL 
ID_B    F   F   L   L   L   L   
SCORE    1.333   0.667   1.636   0.000   1.091   0.545
```

I want to make square of each values in the "SCORE" row of both the files and then multiply them, like; file1 SCORE AAA to LLL with the corresponding file2 SCORE AAA to LLL:

```
 ie (0.750 * 0.750) * (1.333 * 1.333)
    (0.000 * 0.000) * (0.667 * 0.667)
     and so on...
```

Please help me writing this program in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the squares in an array, multiply by the next squares when you meet them:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @results;
while (<>) {
    if (/^SCORE/) {
        my @scores = split;
        shift @scores;
        $_ *= $_ for @scores;
        if (@results) {
            @results = map { $_ * shift @scores } @results;
        } else {
            @results = @scores;
        }
    }
}

print "@results\n";
```

Save to `mutliply.pl`, run as `multiply.pl file1 file2`.

Output:

```
0.9995000625 0 1.965749810704 0 1.968481956676 0
```

Comment: thanks for the code its perfectly working, however if the row header of file2 changes from "SCORE" to some other name say "COUNT", then how it can be done?